# Проблема с сортировкой массива в C#

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь сделать сортировку массива, при которой все нули должны остаться слева(в начале массива), а единицы должны оказаться справа(в конце массива).

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter num");
int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Random rand = new Random();
int[] myArray = new int[arraySize];
for(int i = 0; i != myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = rand.Next(0, 2);
            Console.Write($"{myArray[i]} ");
        }
```

Этот кусочек кода(код выше) просит ввести в консоль целое число, которое будет определять размер массива. Если число 5 то размер массива будет равен 5 int[5]. Далее этот массив заполняется случайными числами 0 или 1.
И массив выводится в консоль.

```
int bottom = myArray.Length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i != myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] == 1)
            {
                for (int j = bottom; j != 0; j--)
                {
                    if(myArray[j] == 0)
                    {
                        myArray[i] = 0;
                        myArray[j] = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
for (int i = 0; i != myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{myArray[i]} ");
        }
Console.ReadKey();
```

Данный кусочек выполняет сортировку массива. Сначала перебираем массив сначала и ищем единицу(1). Как только её нашли перебираем массив с конца в поисках нуля(0), нашли и поменяли местами. И так проделываем со всеми остальными числами и выводим массив.

**ПРОБЛЕМНАЯ ЧАСТЬ**
В большинстве случаев последний элемент массива оказывается нулём(0), а должен быть единицей(1). В чём может быть прооблема??

Comment: А System.Linq принципиально не желаете использовать?

Comment: @LRSM Не использую, так как только учусь работать с массивами. Если вы имели ввиду воспользоваться методами сортировки по типу Array.Sort().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, проблема в том, что на последнем шаге мы нашли единицу в конце, после этого  зачем-то ищем 0 в начале, и меняем их.

Ограничьте область поиска

```
for (int j = bottom; j > i; j--)
```

А ещё лучше завести правый и левый индексы, и, подобно процедуре разделения Хоара в быстрой сортировке, останавливаться, когда они сойдутся вместе. Набросок:

```
l = 0
r = myArray.Length - 1
while l < r
    while myArray[l] = 0
       l++
    while myArray[r] = 1
       r--
    if l < r 
        myArray[l] = 0
        myArray[r] = 1
        l++
        r--
```